# How to record on noname camera

Tags: windows-10, webcam

I have a noname Chinese camera and I want to use it when I'm not at home so I will be able to record what is going on. It has a motion detector. The problem is I cant record with it. I can connect to it and move it around but that is all.

I was using it two years ago and I remember it was some option but I don't remember anymore what I had to do. I used more then 10 hrs and can't find an answer.

What could be wrong?

When I check some options click back to camera view and for like a second I see two more buttons which are for recording, but then they disappear.

Comment: You need to mention the model of your webcam otherwise nobody would be able to help you.

Comment: hey, if you would read you would see i wrote no name. that means i dont know about model or anything from camera...it just says ip wireless/wired camera. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Just tossing an idea at you,

Have you tried using a third-party application to capture it?

If you can log into it, you might try adding it to a capture application.   I use [BlueIris](http://blueirissoftware.com/), but it's a paid solution.   They do have a trial version you could try to see if you can tap the cameras video source.

I've also extensively used [ispyconnect](http://www.ispyconnect.com/)  it worked fine but didn't have the built-in local server functions i was looking for.    [BlueIris](http://blueirissoftware.com/) solved my local server needs and much much more.

If you do try one of these solutions, when picking out the type of camera within the software,  try to locate the brand in the list, but if you can't find it because of the no name Chinese thing, try to match up the no name model to a brand name model (something similar).   Good luck.

Comment: thanx, but i dont want third-party application specially not the one which i should pay for..

Comment: I've worked with many types of cameras.  Oftentimes the software/firmware that comes with these cameras, especially the noname chinese types don't function very well.  ispyconnect is the best free security camera software i've seen, but it is 3rd party.    Good luck is about the best thing i can say.